# *ngFor won't work when used in imported component

Tags: angular, typescript

**Error** I'm getting:

> Can't bind to 'ngforOf' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.
>   ("]*ngfor="let item of [1, 2, 3]"> {{item}} ")

Description:

I encountered a strange problem, I was trying to use *ngFor in my application but it won't work in any possible combination. I tried using BrowserModule, CommonModule. Both failed. Any ideas why I can't get this to work?

nav.component.ts

```
import {OnInit, Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'global-nav',
    template: `
        <div *ngFor="let item of [1, 2, 3]">
            {{item}}
        </div>
    `
})

export class NavComponent implements OnInit {

    private navigation;

    constructor() {
        this.navigation = 
        [
            {
                "href": "#homepage",
                "label": "Homepage"
            }
        ]
    }
    ngOnInit() {

    }
}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { NavComponent } from './components/global/nav/nav.component';
import { MainComponent } from './components/main/main.component';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: MainComponent,
    data: { title: 'Homepage' }
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: '',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavComponent,
    MainComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(
      appRoutes
    ),
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

app.component.ts

No need for it only code for setting up title.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack -p",
    "watch": "webpack -p -w"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/core-js": "^0.9.42",
    "@types/node": "^8.0.12",
    "babel-core": "^6.25.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.4",
    "file-loader": "^0.11.2",
    "html-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.3",
    "postcss-loader": "^2.0.6",
    "precss": "^2.0.0",
    "progress-bar-webpack-plugin": "^1.9.3",
    "pug": "^2.0.0-rc.3",
    "pug-html-loader": "^1.1.5",
    "pug-loader": "^2.3.0",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
    "style-loader": "^0.18.2",
    "ts-loader": "^2.2.2",
    "typescript": "^2.4.1",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.9",
    "webpack": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^4.3.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.3.6",
    "@angular/core": "^4.3.6",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.3.6",
    "@angular/http": "^4.3.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.3.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.3.6",
    "@angular/router": "^4.3.6",
    "core-js": "^2.5.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.3",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.17"
  }
}
```

I'm running out of ideas and I can't find anything about this.  Maybe someone here can help me with this.

Fixed:

Webpack was making my templates into lowercase. And so all my *ngFor became *ngfor

> [*ngFor won't work when used in imported component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46200607/ngfor-wont-work-when-used-in-imported-component?noredirect=1#comment79365650_46200954)

Comment: haver you tried adding `trackBy: $index` to your *ngFor?

Comment: @Roysh not before but now I did, the same effect but it added `Can't bind to 'ngforTrackBy' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.`

Comment: Update your packages

Comment: its not the template syntax... that works fine in one of mine. Must be the setup / system / npm modules

Comment: @Vega It was the first thing I did. No effect.

Comment: what I would do:
save the array as parameter in your controller: `private numArr = [1, 2, 3];`
Then in the template `<div *ngFor="let item of numArr trackBy: $index">`

Comment: @wheelerI just added package.json if you want to take a look at it.

Comment: @Roysh I tried that as well, same effect.

Comment: Compare this project to yours : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xhpehh?file=app%2Fapp.module.ts.

Comment: If you get the error `Can't bind to 'ngforOf'` then you wrote `*ngfor` instead of `*ngFor`

Comment: fixed, looks like webpack was in fault. @amal found a webpack related issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you try changing the order of imports on the `AppModule` so that `BrowserModule` comes before the `RouterModule` ?

**EDIT/UPDATE (for visibility):**

Looks like it is related to this [issue](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/html-loader/issues/67).

Comment: This gives no effect.

Comment: Just noted this upon @yurzui's comment. Feels like it is related to this [issue](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/html-loader/issues/67).

Comment: Just curious, did you have to change the `html-loader` config as part of the fix as mentioned in the link?

Comment: I just added options from this comment https://github.com/webpack-contrib/html-loader/issues/67#issuecomment-277502048 to my html-loader options in my webpack config.

Comment: Nice to know that fixed it!